# Getting "compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization" with "xs:any"

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have the following xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any processContents="skip" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and the following bindings:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="format.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:any">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType name="org.w3c.dom.Element"
                     parseMethod="leif.ElementFormatter.parseElement"
                     printMethod="leif.ElementFormatter.printString" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

But when I run xjc...
`xjc -p leif -b bindings.xml format.xsd`

I get the following errors:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  line 9 of file:/C:/Users/leif/workspace/doughan/src/main/resources/bindings.xml

[ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
  line 7 of file:/C:/Users/leif/workspace/doughan/src/main/resources/format.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

It happens only when defining `javaType` for an `xs:any`, and when I change it to `xs:element` it works. But I really need it to be `xs:any`.

My goal is to get a class like that:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)
    @XmlAnyElement
    String any;
}
```